# I installed python 2.7.3 via brew,but virtualenv always use 2.7.1,why?

Tags: python, virtualenv, homebrew, mac-frameworks

The system default python is:

```
$ /usr/bin/python --version
Python 2.7.1
```

my `$PATH` is

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin
```

I installed `python 2.7.3` via `homebrew`,

```
$ brew install python --universal --framework
```

and linked it,

```
$ cd /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
$ sudo mv Current _Current
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current
```

but when I make a virtualenv, it's still `2.7.1`

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.3

$ virtualenv venv
$ cd venv;source bin/activate
(venv) $ python --version
Python 2.7.1
```

How to solve it?

Comment: You need to use virtualenv's `-p` flag. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv

Comment: (or install virtualenv with python 2.7.3, which will add it to /opt)

Comment: What is the output of `which virtualenv` and `which python`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From virtualenv's help message:

```
 -p PYTHON_EXE, --python=PYTHON_EXE
                        The Python interpreter to use, e.g.,
                        --python=python2.5 will use the python2.5 interpreter
                        to create the new environment.  The default is the
                        interpreter that virtualenv was installed with
```

You probably installed virtualenv with Python 2.7.1 and it works as designed. You can use the -p option to use another version in your virtual env.